# problem happen while enabling or disabling the mobile data in android

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, mobile-application

I have a exception happen while I run this source:

```
public void setMobileDataState(boolean mobileDataEnabled) {
    try {
        TelephonyManager telephonyService = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = telephonyService.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setDataEnabled", boolean.class);
        if (null != setMobileDataEnabledMethod) {
            setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(telephonyService, mobileDataEnabled);

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Error setting mobile data state", ex);
    }
}
```

**Exception:**

> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: then you *obviously* need to fix the exception. But we win't be able to help while you are hiding the exception details from us.

Comment: this exception raised when i run tha app,
"java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"@VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: on which mob you're testing this code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this piece of code in my application. It is working fine for me. Hope this helps you.

For Checking if data is enabled or not you can call  `getMobileDataState()`

For Setting it to Enable or Disable you can call `setMobileDataState(boolean)`. Pass true to Enable Mobile Data and false to Disable Mobile Data

```
   /*Changing mobile data state -  True to turn it ON*/
public void setMobileDataState(boolean mobileDataEnabled) {

    try {
        final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final Class<?> conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
        final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
        iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
        final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
        final Class<?> iConnectivityManagerClass = Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
        final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, mobileDataEnabled);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Toasty.error(Main.this, "Exception: "+ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/* getting mobile data current state - returns True if ON*/
public boolean getMobileDataState() {
    try {
        TelephonyManager telephonyService = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        Method getMobileDataEnabledMethod = telephonyService.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getDataEnabled");
        if (null != getMobileDataEnabledMethod) {
            boolean mobileDataEnabled = (Boolean) getMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(telephonyService);
            return mobileDataEnabled;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Toasty.error(Main.this, "Exception: "+ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Call this where you want to **Turn On Mobile data**

```
setMobileDataState(true);
```

Call this where you want to **Turn OFF Mobile data**

```
setMobileDataState(false);
```

**Update:**

You need to add `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` permission in your **Manifest.xml**

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                    android.Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE}, 101);

     } else {
                setMobileDataEnabled(true);
     }
```

Then in `onRequestPermissionsResult`

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == 101) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            setMobileDataEnabled(true);
        } else {
            Toasty.error(this, "Permission required to perform this action..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            showAlert();
        }
    }
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

**ShowAlertDialog**

```
private void showAlert(){
                    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    dialog.setCancelable(false);
                    dialog.setTitle("Permissions");
                    dialog.setMessage("Please allow this permission in Settings.");
                    dialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent();
                            intent.setAction(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                            intent.setData(uri);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(Settings.this, Settings.class));
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183005/discussion-on-answer-by-ali-ahmed-problem-happen-while-enabling-or-disabling-the).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get and invoke a method using reflection

```
 Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod =
 telephonyService.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("setDataEnabled",
 boolean.class);
 if (null != setMobileDataEnabledMethod) {
    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(telephonyService, mobileDataEnabled);

 }
```

`java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` is a general-purpose exception that's thrown if your code had any problem in running the reflection code. Here, it can  mean two things:

1. your program was not able to find the method that you are looking for, which is quite possible since `setDataEnabled` was added in api 26 (ref : [android docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#setDataEnabled(boolean)))

You shouldn't rely on this method if you are running your app devices with api < 26 too.

2. you don't have permission to invoke this method. You need to have  `MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` for that.

You can call `<invocationTargetExceptionObject>.getCause()` to get the real exception behind this.

Comment: thanq for your reply, hope this will me for my application @Yashasvi

Comment: im using the same permission here and also im using the api<26 device but when i run the application boolean error will rise@Yashsvi

Comment: Have you asked (and graanted) the permission at runtime?

Comment: That's the problem. You need to ask the permission at runtime. See: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Comment: int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Main2Activity.this,Manifest.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE);

        if (result == granted) {
            }

this is what i have to use,when i run the app, the permission is denied...
i dnt know what to do...@Yashasvi

Comment: when im using the modify permission its show that is protected permission so we cant access...anyother solution is there for access this permission...@Yashasvi